# Google Cloud Logging Ruby: Cannot find certain logs

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am having an issue finding logs from the [google-cloud-logging ruby gem](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-logging).

I can find these logs through my google cloud console with the advanced search: `jsonPayload.requestId=875325619`

Which returns multiple results, one basic example:

`{
 insertId: "epfh5dffj67k5"
 jsonPayload: {
  requestId: 875325619
  request: {…}
  timeSeconds: 5.296060973778367
 }
 resource: {
  type: "gce_instance"
  labels: {…}
 }
 timestamp: "2017-05-08T19:31:20.145488859Z"
 severity: "WARNING"
 logName: "projects/myproject/logs/mylog"
}`

However through the ruby agent this returns an empty array:

`logging = Google::Cloud::Logging.new
logging.entries filter: "jsonPayload.requestId=875325619"
=> []`

However looking for a different log message I send works:

`logging.entries filter: 'jsonPayload.uploadKey="example"'
[#<Google::Cloud::Logging::Entry:0x00000008e6ea30 (data here)>]`

That data looks like this:

`{
 insertId: "8w81fbg2a077zl"
 jsonPayload: {
  processingTime: 0.79228602
  uploadType: "type"
  uploadKey: "example"
 }
 resource: {
  type: "gce_instance"
  labels: {…}
 }
 timestamp: "2017-05-08T18:58:11Z"
 labels: {…}
 logName: "projects/myproject/logs/otherapp"
}`

Why can I find one set of log messages and not the other?

Comment: This will probably make no difference, but have you tried wrapping the `requestId` value in quotes? jsonPayload.requestId="875325619"

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

It may take longer time for Stackdriver Logging to search through entries with just unindexed fields, such as `jsonPayload.FIELD`. The service may return the first page of result after a certain time limit, even if that first page is empty. You will be able to query through all the pages by calling:
`logging.entries(filter: "jsonPayload.requestId=875325619").all.to_a`

Note this may fire multiple requests and take longer time.

One thing I find helpful is to always restrict the `filter` by including the indexed fields. Namely the `resource.type` field.

If you change your query code to:

`logging.entries filter: "resource.type=gce_instance AND 
  jsonPayload.requestId=875325619"`

it should return the correct entries and run faster.